# fetch all fields whose data type is phone

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to fetch such fields whose data type is `Phone` and displaying all those field name in visual source page listview. But i am really not sure that how shall i fire the metadata query to get such field name from different modules.

I want to fetch such fields from module customer, cases , account , opportunities and contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to go to the Metadata or Tooling APIs to get this done; all the information you need is available through [describe results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe). You'd be looking at the `getType()` in each field's [`DescribeFieldResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe). Here's a quick sketch:

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()) {
    DescribeFieldResult dfr = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();

    if (dfr.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Phone) {
        System.debug(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Note that you definitely want `getType()`, not `getSOAPType()`, which returns the lower-level type like `String`.

If you want to iterate over multiple sObjects, you could make use of [`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_methods_system_schema) to index into sObject describe information by a string, and iterate over a list of sObject names in which you're interested.

Comment: So for each object i have to perform the same operation ? is there a way to do it in a one go using SOSQL ?

Comment: No, you can't query this information using regular SOQL. You'd have to try something with the Tooling API, which requires a callout. Use describes. They're faster and easier.

Comment: i will give it a try with Tooling API although i am accepting your answer :)

Comment: Using this query i can fetch it in one go `'https://domain.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,FieldDefinition.DataType,FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName+IN+(\'Account\',\'Contact\')+AND+FieldDefinition.DataType+IN+(\'Phone\')'`but not sure how would i parse `HttpResponse` into some meaningful custom class